# passing many fields to next stage in aggregation pipeline

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Please let me know the C# equivalent of below MongoDB query. It works fine in Robo3T for MongoDB

```
db.UserProfile.aggregate([          
    {
      $project: {
         SName:1,
         FName:1,
         DemRole: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$DemRole",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.Name", "FO" ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post the C# entities, please?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by C# entities?

Comment: I'm referring to the types/classes that your code contains. The ones that expose the `SName`, `FName` and `DemRole` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve this by below C# code

```
var stage1 = "{ $project: { SName: 1, FName: 1, DemRole: { $filter: { input: '$DemRole', as: 'item', cond: { $eq: ['$$item._id', '5bc49241f12541c3aaa098ee'  ] } } } } }";


                var query = collection.Aggregate(new AggregateOptions() { AllowDiskUse = true })

                            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(stage1).ToEnumerable();



                return query?.Select(point => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<RetUserProfile4Role>(point)).ToList();
```